# "Where" or "How" for asking " in nature"

Tags: exam-questions

> Bti is found **in nature.**

If I make a question on the word "in nature", which question word will be suitable? The doubt is that I think "in nature" is meant for " the way Bti lives".

> Where is Bti found?
>
> How is Bti found?

Comment: See if you can guess. Hint: *where* refers to places and *how* to methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence:

> Bti is found **in nature.**

I think your confusion lies between 'where' and 'How'. If you want to question "In which place/location Bti is found?" You should use **Where** and If you want to question "In what way/manner/method Bti is found?" you should use **How**

It's clear in your sentence that Bti is found in nature. Nature is the place/location where you find Bti.
Therefore, you should write as:

> Where is Bti found?

I would advice you to read where http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/where and How http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/how

Comment: If you have any confusion about how and where, please let us know. If you Have any querry, Please comment

Comment: The doubt is that I think  "in nature" is meant for " the way Bti live".So I ask whether I should use "how". I am also depressed for my question is usually downvoted.

Comment: You'r making a sentence where write 'Bti is found in nature. Here, **In nature** Is a place/location/existence where Bti can be found. So, I don't think 'In nature' refers to the way Bti live. I'd like to ask you, what do you mean by **Bti** ?

Comment: You'r making a sentence where you write 'Bti is found in nature. Here, **In nature** Is a place/location/existence where Bti can be found. So, I don't think 'In nature' refers to the way Bti live. I'd like to ask you, what do you mean by **Bti** ?

Comment: Bacillus Thuringensis  Isralensis.

Comment: What does this mean ?